# My web scraped output is showing a Chinese character

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape the TED.com website for a transcript using Beautiful soup. The scraping runs successfully and saves a Chinese character in the created text file instead of the transcript.
Can someone please tell me how I can get the transcript? Is it a UTF-8 encoding issue?

```
def url_to_transcript(url):
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    text = [div.text for div in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"Grid.Grid--with-gutter.d:f"})]
    print(url)
    return text

urls = ['https://www.ted.com/talks/cameron_russell_looks_aren_t_everything_believe_me_i_m_a_model/transcript']
speaker = ['Cameron']


!mkdir Transcripts
for i, c in enumerate(speaker):
    with open("transcripts/" + c + ".txt","wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(transcripts[i], file)
```

My output on the notepad text file is - ΀煝⸀

And my out on the Jupyter notebook text file is -
Error! Cameron.txt is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled. See Console for more details.

Comment: Why do you expect Pickle output to be human-readable?

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `pickle.dump`, and why do you expect the output to be plain text?

Comment: I want to use the pickled file in a new Python Notebook instead of having to load the data again every single time